# Remove Delta Search from IE / Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, malware

After downloading a python eclipse add-on, I was attacked with the delta-search virus. I tried removing the Delta Search entries using Control Panel as well as the Yantoo entry as suggested by [this article](http://www.2-spyware.com/remove-delta-search.html). I then looked at Chrome extensions and did not find anything relevant - but removed all extensions anyway. I then went to Chrome settings, but it listed Chrome as the default browser, but when I open Chrome or IE, I still get the Delta-Search engine page.

Does anyone have a safe way of removing this awful menace? A trustworthy spyway app. would do if no manual means are possible.

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: To fix it for Chrome, you can probably just set a different start page. But it will have also "infected" IE very thoroughly. I recently cleaned this mess using [Spybot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/mirrors/).